# UIImageView in a UITableViewCell and auto layout not working on cell reuse

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, swift

Cells look right at startup.

Once you scroll to a new cell (obviously dequeReusableCell is getting called), the constraints are lost that previously existed on the cell.

Here's the constraints setup on the imageView in the cell:

[image]

Here's what it looks like at app start (cells laying out as I'd like them)

[image]

When you start scrolling, the reuse of a cell messes up the constraints.

I'm calling layoutIfNeeded() in the updateImage method after the image is set on the cell:

```
 func updateWithImage(image: UIImage) {

    userGroupPhotoImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true;
    userGroupPhotoImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;

    self.userGroupPhotoImageView.image = image
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Cell for row at indexPath:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as MyCell
    cell.nameLabel?.text = "Cell \(indexPath.row)"
    switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        cell.updateWithImage(UIImage(named: "group0")!)
    case 1:
        cell.updateWithImage(UIImage(named: "group1")!)
    case 2:
        cell.updateWithImage(UIImage(named: "group2")!)
    case 3:
        cell.updateWithImage(UIImage(named: "group3")!)
    case 4:
        cell.updateWithImage(UIImage(named: "group4")!)
    case 5:
        cell.updateWithImage(UIImage(named: "IMG_0184")!)
    default:
        cell.updateWithImage(UIImage(named: "IMG_0185")!)
    }

    return cell
}
```

What it looks like once you start scrolling:

Scroll down:

[image]

Scroll back up to top;

[image]

Constraints on ImageView:

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me why you are using the updateWithImage: method. The first two lines only need to be executed once, and would better be done in the cell's init code (and you shouldn't need the layoutIfNeeded line at all).

Comment: So what was needed was setting the imageView.image to nil on prepareForReuse()  I'd like to know WHY that is.

Answer (score 0):

setNeedsLayout and layoutIfNeeded needed to be called after each time the image is set and the ImageView.image had to be set to nil on each re-use.  :|

```
class UserGroupCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var userGroupNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var userGroupPhotoImageView: UIImageView! {
    didSet {
        userGroupPhotoImageView.clipsToBounds = true;
        userGroupPhotoImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true;
        userGroupPhotoImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    }
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    userGroupPhotoImageView.image = nil
}

func updateWithImage(image: UIImage) {

    self.userGroupPhotoImageView.image = image
    self.setNeedsLayout()
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on with your app, because I've copied your code, and I don't see the same problem as you do. I do get some constraint warnings in the console, but those go away if I just remove the layoutIfNeeded call (from your original code). You really shouldn't need to call setNeedsLayout or layoutIfNeeded, or set the image to nil. It's hard to tell from your image which constraints you have; do you have top and bottom constraints between your image view and the cell?

Comment: leading, top, trailing, bottom on the ImageView in relation to ContentView.

Comment: I'll keep this answer un-checked until we can determine what is the actual issue.  Posted the constraints btw above.

Comment: I get warnings in the console when I put a height constraint on the image view. It would probably better to delete that, and set the rowHeight property of the table view to define the height instead.

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn't find any answer.
You should do it programatically. And set the constraints in the

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{
```

method.
This way you can be sure about what happens.